# Excel addin office.js - How to track row changes

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I'm develping an Excel addin with office.js and I want to track row change events.

I'm fetching data from a DBMS with technical Ids but I don't want to print ids into the sheet.

My main issue is to identify univocally the edited row: when user perform row sorting I'm loosing any reference.

I have tried several approaches:

- `Range` [excel.binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.binding?view=excel-js-preview) row by row (a binding for each row)
- `Table` [excel.binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.binding?view=excel-js-preview) on entire dataset
- A combination of handlers such as:

  - BindingDataChanged
  - TableDataChanged
- Named items

Below a gist that can be directly imported into ScriptLab with the first two options looking the most promising
https://gist.github.com/webartoli/86a19ffa0e683aa1d204eabaaeb09dd1

Can anyone help me in being able to uniquely identify a row in events ?

Repro steps:

- Click a button to create dataset and set handlers
- Sort the second column ascending: the first rows becomes id=5
- Edit the first row

How can i get from events that row with id=5 is edited without printing id column on sheet ?
I except this from "binding" feature but I cannot find a way.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you don't want to expose the DBMS IDs on the sheet. Also, I think https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/officeextension.clientrequestcontext?view=common-js-preview#office-officeextension-clientrequestcontext-trackedobjects-member is intended for this kind of scenario.

Comment: IDs are GUID and the user can edit existing rows or adds records. The common interaction that we have observed: is "copy paste" existing row, then change some specific cell. 

In this scenario the ID of the new row is "duplicate" becouse of copy paste, and a guid requires a non-small portion of the viewport. 

Removing the IDs from the sheet would be optimal for us.

Comment: I think you should explore using tracked objects.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'll explore tracked object!

Comment: I have been exploring TrackedObject. As I understand it, the intent of TrackedObject is to keep instances of the object alive between different `context.sync()` and I cannot find a way to use it to implement this scenario. How were you thinking of applying it ?

Comment: I haven't tried it. I was just thinking that if you had a tracked object reference to each row, that might enable you to keep rows identified without an ID column.